# Implement TraitA for all types that implement TraitB

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to understand why the following code does not compile:

```rust
trait Vehicle {
    fn get_num_wheels(&self) -> u32;
}

impl std::fmt::Display for dyn Vehicle {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Has {} wheels", self.get_num_wheels())
    }
}

struct Car();

impl Vehicle for Car {
    fn get_num_wheels(&self) -> u32 {
        4
    }
}

fn main() {
    let car = Car {};
    println!("{car}");
}
```

---

```
error[E0277]: `Car` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> src/main.rs:21:16
   |
21 |     println!("{car}");
   |                ^^^ `Car` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Car`
```

I would think that if I implemented `Display` for `Vehicle`, then all structs that implement `Vehicle` would also inherit `Vehicle`'s implementation of `Display`. I can see why this would be an issue if `Car` tried to make its own implementation of `Display`, but this is not the case here.

I know I can fix this example by changing

```rust
impl std::fmt::Display for dyn Vehicle
```

to

```rust
impl std::fmt::Display for Car
```

but for non-trivial examples, this seems really verbose. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure Rust currently supports this kind of "inheritance". A trait can't force another trait on something. It's worth noting that instead of a parent-child relation, Rust tends towards enums like `Vehicle::Car(c)` or `Vehicle::Motorbike(m)` each of wraps another type and can implement `Display` at a higher level. You could also have `VehicleContainer<V> where V : Vehicle` and that `Vehicle` is some kind of trait as you have here, though the container is what implements `Display`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `dyn Vehichle` is not the same as the trait `Vehichle`. Specifically, it's what's called a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html), and can hold a value of any type that implements the trait.

Therefore, when you implement `Display for dyn Vehichle`, you only implement it for that particular type, but not for any other type that implements the trait.

If you want every type that implements a trait `TraitA` (e.g. `Vehicle`) to also implement a trait `TraitB` (e.g. `Display`), there are two ways of approaching this, each with some caveats.

The first is to have a blanket implementation. Due to the [orphan rule](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#trait-implementation-coherence), this can only be done if `TraitB` is defined in the same crate, so this wouldn't work with `Display` which is defined in the standard library.

```rust
impl<T: TraitA> TraitB for T {
    // ...
}
```

The second approach is to declare `TraitB` a supertrait of `TraitA`. This will work even if `TraitB` is not defined in the same crate, however this will require any trait that implements `TraitA` to also implement `TraitB`, which again due to the orphan rule may not be possible for types that are not defined in the same crate.

```rust
trait TraitA: TraitB {
    // ...
}


impl TraitA for SomeType {}

// required by the above, else the compiler will complain
impl TraitB for SomeType {}
```

In either case, you will not be able to implement a trait from a different crate, such as `Display`, on a type from a different crate. The first approach won't work for your code, but the second can work since the `Car` type is defined in the same crate.

---

An approach to circumvent the issue entirely is instead to have a "displayable wrapper type" that can wrap any type that implements `Vehicle`. For example:

```rust
struct DisplayVehicle<'a, V: ?Sized + Vehicle>(&'a V);

impl<'a, V: ?Sized + Vehicle> std::fmt::Display for DisplayVehicle<'a, V> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Has {} wheels", self.0.get_num_wheels())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let car = Car {};
    println!("{}", DisplayVehicle(&car));
}
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba8040a8669fa7d5f663d8eda8085f9f))

While this does become slightly more verbose, it avoids the orphan rule entirely and therefore doesn't have the same issues as trying to implement `Display` directly on every `Vehicle` type. Additionally, since the `Display` implementation isn't actually related to the type itself but to the *trait*, this may be generally a more idiomatic approach to the solve this problem.

Comment: This answer should be the canonical duplicate of questions like that!

Answer (score 2):

It works if you cast directly to the trait object btw:

```rust
trait Vehicle {
    fn get_num_wheels(&self) -> u32;
}

impl std::fmt::Display for dyn Vehicle { 

     fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
         write!(f, "Has {} wheels", self.get_num_wheels())
     }
 }

struct Car();

impl Vehicle for Car {
    fn get_num_wheels(&self) -> u32 {
        4
    }
}

fn main() {
    let car = Car {};
    println!("{}", &car as &dyn Vehicle);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=34f17655e85b3039c327846f5b8a9568